# C# to Objective-C Translator?

Tags: c#, objective-c, c#-4.0

Does anyone know where i can get a C# -> Objective-C translator?
I found ones for C# -> VB or C# -> Ruby or C# -> Java but I need one for Objective-C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no free translators out there that I know of.

You can check out [monotouch](http://xamarin.com/monotouch).

Comment: Oded: Have you used this? How efficient does it translate the use of delegates? I'm curious about this. Does it simply turn them into `NSPredicate`s?

Comment: No, I never developed for iOS.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check [CocoaSharp - Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/CocoaSharp)